# Using for loops with nested loops in python

Tags: python, for-loop, printing, nested-loops

I need to print each element with its atomic number and weight each on a separate line, with a colon between the name and atomic number and weight, however, it prints each three times, I understand why but have no idea how to remedy it. Help

Here is the code I used:

```
elements = [['beryllium', 4, 9.012], ['magnesium', 12, 24.305], ['calcium', 20, 40.078], ['strontium', 38, 87.620], ['barium', 56, 137.327], ['radium', 88, 266.000]]

for x in elements:
    for i in x:
        print str(x[0]), ':', str(x[1]), str(x[2])
```

Comment: Why do you have the extra `for i in x:` line? It seems to do nothing except make the code repeat three times. Remove that, that's all.

Comment: You do not need to call `str` on each item that you want to `print`.  Doing `print x[0], ':', x[1], x[2]` would work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping over the 3 nested elements; simply remove the nested `for`:

```
for x in elements:
    print str(x[0]), ':', str(x[1]), str(x[2])
```

You can also have Python unpack the elements into separate names; note that the explicit `str()` calls are not needed here as you are not concatenating the values; let `print` take care of converting the values to strings for you:

```
for name, number, weight in elements:
    print name, ':', number, weight
```

Next, use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to get more control over the output:

```
for name, number, weight in elements:
    print '{:>10}: {:3d} {:7.3f}'.format(name, number, weight)
```

and you get nicely formatted output:

```
>>> for name, number, weight in elements:
...     print '{:>10}: {:3d} {:7.3f}'.format(name, number, weight)
... 
 beryllium:   4   9.012
 magnesium:  12  24.305
   calcium:  20  40.078
 strontium:  38  87.620
    barium:  56 137.327
    radium:  88 266.000
```